# Xcode / iPhone Enterprise Distribution Certificate Made By Other Person

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution, enterprise

There is an Enterprise Distribution Provision that was created by another person that is no longer here (before me).  Getting the development provision / certificate was fine, by adding myself to the team, etc.  But what is the best way to clear the "No Valid / Matching Certificate" for the Distribution Provision when building for release / distribution?  Will we have to make another Distribution Provision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dont have the keys with which the certs were signed, then you'll need to create new certs with a new key, and sign your profiles using these new certs.

Comment: Could not find the public keys, had to remake, etc.